# System corrupted - where do I see what was the problem?

Tags: 16.04, security

Today, my laptop suddenly stopped working. I restarted several times but result was that on startup it freezes.
Then I completelly removed Variety wallpaper changer from boot options in safe mode. It worked then from second attempt.

How to see what was causing problems? Is there some log file in ubuntu?

PS. I found something
[image]

Comment: Hardware issues can sometimes be unpredictable like this. You may want to check the SMART status on your drives (using Disks or `smartctl`) and also check the filesystems (using `fsck`).

Answer (score 1):

The Boot-Log file is most likely at either
    `/var/log/boot.log`
or
    `/var/log/dmesg`

You can alse try
    `journalctl -b`